# How to mount filesystems on OL8

Tags: filesystems, mount, lvm

I cannot mount the filesystems below on my Oracle Linux 8:

```
/dev/mysql_vg/mysql_lv
/dev/mysql_bck_vg/mysql_bck_lv
```

How I created the volume groups:

```
vgcreate mysql_vg /dev/sdb
vgcreate mysql_bck_vg /dev/sdc
```

How I created the logical volumes:

```
lvcreate -n mysql_lv --size 1020MiB mysql_vg
lvcreate -n mysql_bck_lv --size 1020MiB mysql_bck_vg
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mysql_vg/mysql_lv 
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mysql_bck_vg/mysql_bck_lv
```

My setup:

```
[root@dummy mysql]# lsblk
NAME                           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                              8:0    0   30G  0 disk 
├─sda1                           8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2                           8:2    0   28G  0 part 
  ├─system_vg-root_lv          252:0    0   10G  0 lvm  /
  ├─system_vg-swap_lv          252:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─system_vg-var_log_lv       252:2    0    4G  0 lvm  /var_log_lv
  ├─system_vg-var_log_audit_lv 252:3    0    2G  0 lvm  /var_log_audit_lv
  ├─system_vg-home_lv          252:4    0    2G  0 lvm  /home_lv
  ├─system_vg-tmp_lv           252:5    0    2G  0 lvm  /tmp_lv
  ├─system_vg-var_lv           252:6    0    2G  0 lvm  /var_lv
  └─system_vg-var_tmp_lv       252:7    0    4G  0 lvm  /var_tmp_lv
sdb                              8:16   0    1G  0 disk 
└─mysql_vg-mysql_lv            252:9    0 1020M  0 lvm  
sdc                              8:32   0    1G  0 disk 
└─mysql_bck_vg-mysql_bck_lv    252:8    0 1020M  0 lvm  
sr0                             11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

When attempting to mount them, I get these errors:

```
[root@dummy ~]# mount /dev/mysql_vg/mysql_lv /var/lib/mysql
mount: /var/lib/mysql: unknown filesystem type.

[root@dummy ~]# mount /dev/mysql_bck_vg/mysql_bck_lv /var/lib/mysql/
mount: /var/lib/mysql: unknown filesystem type.
```

Comment: Hi Paraskeva, I assume "OL8" means Oracle Linux 8, right? Please undo my edit if that was wrong.

Comment: Try `mount` with the `-t ext4` option to make Linux know which filesystem type to mount.